# Non- overlapping sphere condition

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

I want to check a condition so that two spheres do not overlap. It would mean distance between two spheres should be greater than (r1 + r2). I have posted the full code below, there seems to be something wrong with the second function which checks for non-overlapping condition. I can run the code without that condition but when i include that it doesn't execute. The value of the variables are dims = [ 10 10 10 ] and  n = 25; Let me know what you think, is there any other better way for formulating this condition?

```
function [ c r ] = randomSphere( dims )
% creating one sphere at random inside [0..dims(1)]x[0..dims(2)]x...
% radius and center coordinates are sampled from a uniform distribution 
% over the relevant domain.
% output: c - center of sphere (vector cx, cy,... )
%         r - radius of sphere (scalar)
r = rand(1); % you might want to scale this w.r.t dims or other consideration
c = r + rand( size(dims) )./( dims - 2*r ); % make sure sphere does not exceed boundaries


**function ovlp = nonOverlapping( centers, rads )
% check if several spheres with centers and rads overlap or not
ovlp = false;
if numel( rads ) == 1
return; % nothing to check for a single sphere
end
dst = sqrt( sum( bsxfun( @minus, permute( centers, [1 3 2] ),...
                             permute( centers, [3 1 2] ) ).^2, 3 ));
ovlp = dst >= bsxfun( @plus, rads, rads.' ); %' all distances must be smaller than r1+r2
ovlp = any( ovlp(:) ); % all must not overlap**

function [centers, rads] = sampleSpheres( dims, n )
% dims is assumed to be a row vector of size 1-by-ndim

% preallocate
ndim = numel(dims);
centers = zeros( n, ndim );
rads = zeros( n, 1 );
ii = 1;
while ii <= n
[centers(ii,:), rads(ii) ] = randomSphere( dims );     
if nonOverlapping( centers(1:ii,:), rads(1:ii) )
  ii = ii + 1; % accept and move on
 end
end
disp (centers);
disp (rads);
```

Comment: `whos` info on `centers` and `rads`?. Maybe provide an example of them?

Comment: Hey! I just added more detailed explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are adding up new spheres based on the distance between spheres' centers and their radii. So, you need to compare all spheres against the latest addition, which would be `centers(end,:)` and  `rads(end)`.

This is what this function does -

```
function not_ovlp = nonOverlapping( centers, rads )

if numel( rads ) == 1
    not_ovlp = true;
    return; % nothing to check for a single sphere
end

center_dist = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,centers(1:end-1,:),centers(end,:)).^2,2));
radsum = rads(end) + rads(1:end-1);
not_ovlp = all(center_dist > radsum);

return;
```

It gives output as `true` when there is `not an overlap`.

---

**Explanation with an example**

Let's suppose you start adding spheres to this wishlist of non-overlapping ones. So you  select first sphere with center `(1,2,1)` and radius `2`. Then, for the next one you have `(3,4,2)` as the center with a radius of `0.5`.

Thus, you have -

```
centers =[
    1 2 1;
    3 4 2]

rads = [2;0.5]
```

Now, you need to check if this latest sphere overlaps with the earlier selected sphere(s) or not, which you can find out with the earlier listed function -

```
nonOverlapping( centers, rads )
```

It gives `1` suggesting this new addition is non-overlapping one and could be included into the list.

Comment: Hey! It is slightly more complex. I have posted the full code which am trying to run. So if the two spheres overlap, then it should break and look for other random co-ordinates of centers and rads and so on. The whole objective of the code is to generate a random non-overlapping sphere packing in a cube.

Comment: @skonda2 `nonOverlapping` function has to return `true` when not overlapping?

Comment: Yes! So when it returns true that centers and rads becomes a specification for one sphere...so in this way we will add 25 spheres, which will have unique centers and rads.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong because when i call main function sampleSpheres which basically does the allocation of center and radius for all 25 spheres. It does not go forward in the while loop.

Comment: @skonda2 As an experiment try with smaller radii (which gives more chances of finding non-overlapping ones), like `r = rand(1)/10` or `r = rand(1)/20` inside `randomSphere` maybe?

Comment: I am getting the following error 
     
     Error in nonOver (line 3)
     if numel( rads ) == 1

     Output argument "not_ovlp" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "C:\Users\Konda\Documents\MATLAB\nonOver.m>nonOver".
nonOverlapping function id missing something.

Comment: @skonda2 Added `not_ovlp = true;` when `numel(rads) is 1` to skip the first addition. Check out the edited code.

Comment: Yeap! That was the problem. It seems to working. I will trying some extreme cases to make the whole code a bit robust and will visualize the random spheres in a box to make sure everything is fine with packing.

Comment: @skonda2 Exactly, visualizing them would make the solution concrete! Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Or just loop over all possible sphere combinations until either all pass or one fails.

```
ovlp = false;

% assume centers is mx3 matrix for m sphere centres
numSpheres = size(centers,1);

for k=1: numSpheres
    for m=k+1:numSpheres
        dist = sqrt((centers(k,1)-centers(m,1))^2 + (centers(k,2)-centers(m,2))^2 ...
                    + (centers(k,3)-centers(m,3))^2);
        if dist <= (rads(k)+rads(m))
            ovlp = true;
            break;
        end
     end
     if ovlp
         break;
     end
end
```

Unless you need to know which spheres intersect and which don't.

**EDIT** mistake in above inner for loop.  Should iterate from k+1 to numSpheres and not from 2.

Comment: I have posted the full code. So the basic algo is randomSphere will give out a random radius and center. Then nonOverlapping function checks whether the center and rads overlap with the first sphere. If it gives out true, then we have two spheres in the box. It it return false, then it breaks and checks for other centers and radius. It keeps going on till there are 25 spheres in the box.